# How to add link in user menu which is available for loggedin users in drupal

Tags: routes, users

I want to add link for member area in user menu which is only available for logged in user.Please let me know how i can do this.I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken the easy way out on this one with all my projects. I have two menus, one for logged in users and one for logged out. This works because I can set the 'logged out' menu block to show only to anonymous users, and then I can set the logged in for only authenticated users (in block settings). The solution works great with no custom programming needed!